# Vim not recognizing l key &

Tags: vim

I just installed vim on Pop OS 18.04 using

```
sudo apt install vim
```

This a fresh installation and I have not even set up a `.vimrc` file. Whenever I type `&`
key, vim shows a weird `&` character which when copied to some other text field fixes itself automatically I can type in other editors too. Here is a screenshot of the same:[image].

I looked for keymaps and tried opening vim as `vim -u NONE`.

Comment: It's a legit "&" **for that font**. If you want it different, you need to change your terminal font.

Comment: Take a look at the history section of [the wikipedia page for the ampersand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s your font, as mentioned in the comments. The key works fine.